# 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python

I'm getting strange error "'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'"

I haven't used the word "startswith" in my python program.  ?
Does any one how to fix this -- or what it refers to ?

Comment: show us your code and the traceback.

Comment: Since you've fixed it, you should probably either accept an answer, or write up the answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something in your program is trying to call the `startswith` method of an object, probably because it expects it to be a string. You'll have to pay attention to the traceback to see what it is being called on, and why that is an integer instead of a string. Did you pass along an integer where a string was expected?

Comment: how to find which lines causes this errors? Any way to execute python in debug mode

Comment: @lakshmipathi: Like the answer says, look at the traceback.

Comment: yes..i'm using git and found it ..it's with join() which tries to use int and string. using str(id) works ..thanks

Answer (score 5):

`startswith` only works with `strings`.

If you need to check if an `int` starts with a set of numbers, you can convert it to a `string`, i.e.:

```
someint = 1234
if str(someint).startswith("123"):
    # do somenting
```